# To use one GridView / SqlDataSource for the same query but different ConnectionStrings? Or multiple ones for each ConnectionString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm totally new to ASP.NET and C#.
I want to display some information from one of many Databases in a GridView. The query is the same in all cases but the ConnectionString is selected based on a DropDownList.

I was wondering what is the best practice to use in this case?

- Do I create multiple SqlDataSources / GridViews for each ConnectionString and change which one to make visible or hide based on the DropDownList selection?
- Or do I create only one SqlDataSource / GridView and change the ConnectionString programmatically based on the DropDownList selection?

I tried the first way and it works fine but the code looks cluttered as there are many GridViews that are not used most of the time. 
And when I tried the second method, it didn't go very well as I keep getting the following error when I try to change the DataSource of the GridView programmatically in order to refresh it:

> > System.InvalidOperationException: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridViewCustomers'.  Remove one definition.

I used the following code to change the ConnectionString of the SqlDataSource and the DataSource of the GridView programmatically in order to refresh it (every time a search button is clicked, the code checks DropDownList and tries to change connections accordingly):

```
switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString())
            {
                case "30":
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DTconnection"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.SelectCommand = "DisplayCustomer";
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.SelectCommandType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.DataBind();
                    GridViewCustomers.DataSource = SqlDataSourceCustomers;
                    GridViewCustomers.DataBind();
                    GridViewCustomers.Visible = true;
                    break;


                case "20":
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.ConnectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DWahconnection"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.SelectCommand = "DisplayCustomer";
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.SelectCommandType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataSourceCustomers.DataBind();
                    GridViewCustomers.DataSource = SqlDataSourceCustomers;
                    GridViewCustomers.Visible = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    GridViewCustomers.Visible = false;          
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Do you run this code (above) every time the user picks a different connection?

Comment: I have the code in a switch case (I have edited it to include the switch case). And I run it when clicking a search button.

So that every time the search button is clicked, the code checks the dropdownlist and changes connections accordingly.

Comment: For your `case "30"` you perform two `.DataBind()` calls, but for `case "20"` you only do one.  Do either of these cases work better than the other?

Comment: they're different because I was just trying it out. There is no difference. However as I'm totally new to asp.net and c#.. is it a better practice to just use different gridviews and assign them data sources from aspx file instead of changing sources programmatically?

Comment: Using two gridviews would get the job done, but you are close to solving this (in a better way, IMO). The error message has a good hint about what to look-for. Your example code (above) doesn't show any use of `DataSourceID`.  I would look for where DataSourceID is being set and maybe set a breakpoint before `GridViewCusstomers.DataSource` is changed, and inspect it to see if there is a DataSourceID and if setting it to `null` will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. the DataSourceID was set in the aspx file and setting it to null in the code above solved the issue!